Download All Files from SharePoint 2013 On-Premise Without Server Access
I need to download all the files from a SharePoint 2013 on-premise site. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the SharePoint server directly, only the admin control panel via the web interface.
I'm able to log in and manage the site via the SharePoint Central Admin Panel (not server-side).
I don't have the ability to use PowerShell or remote into the server.
I'm looking for a method to download all files from a SharePoint site or library in bulk through the available web interface or some other method that doesn't require server access.
I've tried downloading individual files, but this process is slow and inefficient, especially when dealing with a large number of documents. Is there any built-in functionality or any tools that could help me download everything at once from a document library?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Environment:
SharePoint 2013 (On-Premise)
No server access
Admin control panel access only
